# Datetime in Y-Axis Highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, highcharts

I'm in the middle of building heatmap chart, but i have problem adding datetime in Y axis from timestamp data in my json file, it just showing 00:00:00:001 in my Y axis chart.

This is my code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var options = {
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          type: 'heatmap'
        },
        xAxis: {
          tickPixelInterval: 1000,
          categories: []
        },
          yAxis: {
          type: 'datetime'
                },
        legend: {
          align: 'right',
          layout: 'vertical',
          margin: 0,
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          symbolHeight: 280
        },
        colorAxis: {
          stops: [
            [0, '#3060cf'],
            [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
            [0.9, '#c4463a']
          ],
          min: -5
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            turboThreshold: 0
          }
        },
        series: [{
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000'
          }
        }]
      };

      var ajaxCounter = 0,
        dataArr = [],
        intervalId = setInterval(function() {
          $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
              var categories = [],
                prevCat = -1,
                numb = -1;

              Highcharts.each(data, function(xvals, i) {
                if (prevCat !== xvals[0]) {
                  numb++;

                  prevCat = xvals[0];
                  categories.push((xvals[0]));
                  dataArr.push([numb, ajaxCounter, xvals[2]]);
                } else {
                  dataArr.push([numb, ajaxCounter, xvals[2]]);
                }
              });
              ajaxCounter++;
              options.xAxis.categories = categories;

              options.series[0].data = dataArr;
              var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

              if (ajaxCounter === 24) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
              }
          });
        }, 10000);
    });
```

This is my json file

```
    [
    [100,1474633760,0],
    [200,1474633760,0],
    [300,1474633760,2471.0],
    [400,1474633760,0],
    [500,1474633760,0],
    [600,1474633760,1951.0],
    [700,1474633760,0],
    [800,1474633760,0],
    [900,1474633760,2125.0],
    [1000,1474633760,0]
    ]
```

Thank you for you attention, i hope you guys can help my little project

Comment: So how your data object ctually looks right now? Why you are not using your xVals[1]?

Comment: 1) I don't see where you're actually supplying the `datetime` data to the chart. This will cause your x values to start at 0, and increment by one millisecond per data point.  2) your `timestamps` are in seconds, but they need to be in milliseconds - as it is,  your dates would show up as starting around January 17, 1970 or so. Multiply them by 1,000.

Comment: In fact, right here:  `dataArr.push([numb, ajaxCounter, xvals[2]]);` you are explicitly sending the loop counter as the y value, which means the first data point is 0 milliseconds, the second point is 1 millisecond, etc.

Comment: could you fix my code above ? i already tried to multiply timestamps by 1000, but still get 00:00:00:001.
I'm not good enough at javascript. @jlbriggs

Comment: You need this: ` dataArr.push([numb, ajaxCounter, xvals[2]])` to be something like this: `dataArr.push([numb, (xvals[1] * 1000), xvals[2]])`. You need to multiply the timestamps by 1,000, but you also need to actually send them to the data array.

Comment: @jlbriggs thank for your advice, but now my chart is looks like this http://s9.postimg.org/akwcf30f3/manage.jpg do you know what's wrong in my code ?

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: the json data is in my local directory, i'n not sure how to set up fiddle with json data... @jlbriggs

Comment: If you use the final output to build your fiddle, we can see what's going on (should be able to either use a view source, or console.log(options) and copy as JSON to get the code.

Comment: @jlbriggs this is it, https://jsfiddle.net/5q9zeege/1/ this is the exact problem i've been faced.